# Is it possible to use web sockets for update location coordinates on map?

Tags: php, android, ios, sockets, websocket

For IOS app, Is it possible to use **web sockets** for **update location coordinates on map**? I need to implement the each single coordinate changes should reflect to map for two more users. I want to display users location on map (live update).
http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps
Please suggest me which one is best **http or web sockets**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , web sockets are really helpful for this concept.